# Docker - Pass a environment setting via docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and have a working docker-compose file, apart from one part. What I want to achieve is to set an environment setting so that in my PHP application I can use some variables to determine which resources I load in.

In MAMP PRO, for instance, you can access environment settings on this page:

[image].

In my docker-compose file I have the following:

```
services:
  webserver:
    build: ./docker/webserver
    image: perch
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - C:/websites/sitename/www:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - DEVELOPER_ENV=development
```

At the moment the variable - from what I can tell - isn't being set as my php variables to detect the environment, fail. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a correct way of declaring an environmental variable inside that container. You can attache to it and do 'echo $DEVELOPER_ENV' to see it's there.

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: DEVELOPER_ENV` and if I do `echo $_SERVER["DEVELOPER_ENV"]` I get `Undefined index: DEVELOPER_ENV`

Comment: yea but is the envvar loaded into your container's environment, not the app's environment?  is DEVELOPER_ENV listed in `env | sort`

Comment: I don't know any details about your image. My FPM containers have no problem seeing those variables.

Comment: @mike do you have your image in a repo I could look at? Or I can post my Dockerfile above if it'd help point to any issues.

Comment: @Creek if I run `docker exec projectname_webserver_1 env | sort` I can see the env being set. I assume that's good?

Comment: Yup, no magic there.

Comment: yea so docker is working as expected.  you need to read that variable from the os not the apache environment

Answer (score 1):

Apache by default removes most environment variables for security reasons.
But you can whitelist variables in the `etc/apache2/conf-enabled/expose-env.conf` file.

So I added theses commands to my dockerfile:

`RUN
        echo 'PassEnv DB_PW' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/expose-env.conf \
        && echo 'PassEnv DB_USER' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/expose-env.conf`

Alternatively you can copy or mount the `expose-env.conf`.